# Sum of variances of 2 correlated random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, variance, covariance

I have 2 random variables (RVs) $X$ and $Y$ which are correlated by $\rho$.

$$X, Y \sim N(0, \sigma_1)$$.

X and Y are both multiplied by $Z$ which is also a normal RV, independent from $X$ and $Y$ ($Z \sim N(0, \sigma_2) $).

$$ Out = Z \cdot X + Z \cdot Y $$

If I isolate the variance of Z, I get the sum of of the variance of X and Y.

\begin{align*}
var[Out] &= var[Z]var[X] + var[Z]var[Y] \\
&= var[Z] \cdot \left( var[X] + var[Y] \right)
\end{align*}

Since X and Y are correlated, does this become ?

\begin{gather*}
var[Out]= var[Z] \cdot \left( var[X] + var[Y] + 2cov[X,Y] \right)
\end{gather*}

Or do I just leave $var[X] + var[Y]$ as is ?

Comment: you can't split variances like that. Suppose $Z$ was a nonzero constant, then $Var(ZX) > 0$ but $Var(Z)Var(X)=0$

Comment: @ZoeAllen Im not sure I understand ? Why would $Var(Z)Var(X) = 0$ ? Neither of them are $0$ . I'm basing myself on this work, where they split variances : https://mmuratarat.github.io/2019-02-25/xavier-glorot-he-weight-init

Comment: I made a mistake. Given $X$ and $Z$ have mean $0$ and are independent, you can split the variances.

Comment: @Henry Sorry, I made a mistake in my notation. I meant to say $Out = ZX + ZY$

Comment: Yes: $var[X+Y] = var[X] + var[Y] + 2cov[X,Y] = 2(1+\rho)\sigma_1^2$ here and you have $Out = Z \cdot X + Z \cdot Y=Z \cdot(X+Y)$

Comment: @Henry Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ and $Y$ might not be independent, $ZX$ need not be independent from $ZY$. So your first computation needs a $2\operatorname{cov}(ZX, ZY) = 2\operatorname{var}(Z) \operatorname{cov}(X, Y)$ term, where the equality holds because $Z$ is independent of both $X$ and $Y$. Now if you factor out $\operatorname{var}(Z)$ you get the same expression as the second method.